# How can I access browser history in my iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, safari

I'm trying to build a cleaning app that among other things delete your browser history.

How can I access the history in Chrome and Safari (Xcode7,Swift2)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The app is sandboxed and doesn't have access to those details.

Comment: So there is no way to do it?

Comment: Do you have evidence?