# Swift - Check if website visited

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a method or way in Swift to check if a user has visited a certain webpage or website?

I know a question was asked for this already:

[How can I access browser history in my iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901132/how-can-i-access-browser-history-in-my-ios-project)

Or, maybe, is there a way to track if the phone has made a request from a certain IP?

I just want to create a condition to see if a user has visited my website.

Comment: And on the question you linked, the answer was a rather clear 'no'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access browser history in my iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901132/how-can-i-access-browser-history-in-my-ios-project)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Due to the application sandbox for third party apps, you cannot track/access previous network requests outside your app.

[Learn more about app sandboxing here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is to get current IP of the user:

[Swift - Get device's IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748480/swift-get-devices-ip-address)

Then do a get request to see if it is in my server logs. But this is not very reliable as they may have visited the website on a different network.

Could request a location one the phone and on the browser then compare lat and long to see if in a radius... still, not a reliable solution.